# R shiny session problem in deployed golem application

Tags: r, session, shiny, golem, isolate

I have a shiny application made with golem in which I have a lot of modules (ui and server).
This application is **deployed** and my problem is that when I open 2 windows of my application, the filters of one (window) are applied to the other.
There is no session isolation and I don't know how to do that.

It is quite difficult to reproduce the example here.
Is there an option or a way to isolate each instance of the application?
Is this isolation to be done in the code or is it to be managed by the host?